# FormBuilder validation is not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have this form that implements `FormBuilder`.

I need to show my custom validation message under the input field. With my code below, the validator can make a red "wrong" text appear whenever the input field is blank but it doesn't show my custom validation.

Please see code below for `.html` and `.ts`

```
<form [formGroup]="subscriptionForm">
      <h3 style="color: gray; text-align: center;">Registration</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
            <input type="text" formControlName="UserName" name='UserName' id="UserName" class="form-control" mdbInputDirective>
            <label for="UserName">Your UserName</label>
            <div *ngIf="UserName?.invalid && (UserName?.dirty || UserName?.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
              <div *ngIf="UserName?.errors.required">
                Username is required.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptionForm = this.fb.group({
      UserName: [null, Validators.required],
    });
}
```

I have gone through the Angular - Form validation docs, that's where I got my codes, but I can't get it right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

`*ngIf="UserName?.invalid && (UserName?.dirty || UserName?.touched)"`

To

`*ngIf="subscriptionForm.get('UserName').hasError('required') && subscriptionForm.get('UserName').touched"`

In the view:

```
<div *ngIf="subscriptionForm.get('UserName').hasError('required') && subscriptionForm.get('UserName').touched" class="alert alert-danger">
    Username is required.
</div>
```

Please try this Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5xtbxm?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you. Now it is showing my custom message but the red text 'wrong', which is the default error message, keeps appearing and overlapping my custom message. Is there a way I can turn it off? Some more help please.

Comment: You may have a css issue, can you create a demo that  we can help you more, I'm using what I showed you in my own work without any problem.

Comment: I am acutally using angular mdb for scss. I didn't create any custom css.

Comment: I've included a working demo, you can adapt it to your specific css by adding the required class you want.

Comment: @stack questions: this answer is for the problem of error message not showing, if it shows your custom validation now, accept this answer and add a new question about more specifically a css problem. include then a demo and/or relevant files that can other SO members can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are missing the getter methods from the docs, for example:

```
get name() { return this.heroForm.get('name'); }

get power() { return this.heroForm.get('power'); }
```

So now when they access `name` in their template, they actually access `this.heroForm.get('name')`

SO what you are required to do in your `*ngIf` is check for:

```
subscriptionForm.get('UserName').errors.required
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Can you please show me how to get rid of the red text 'wrong' that comes out by default. It's messing my custom message. Thank you.

Comment: @stackquestions: I don't think there is a default `wrong` text. As @HDJEMAI has added an example, you can refer that. Or else create your own example so that we can debug more.

Comment: This was the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `subscriptionForm.controls.UserName` instead of `UserName` in your view

Answer (score 0):

To access the form's model, you need to use `subscriptionForm.get('UserName')`. For this to work properly, I would set the initial value in your model to an empty string instead of `null`:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptionForm = this.fb.group({
    UserName: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  // also, make access easier using a property...
  get UserName { return this.subscriptionForm.get('UserName'); }
}
```